# Find matching pattern between columns and count for each distinct element in one column

Tags: r, shell, awk, cut

I have a tab delimited file with around 70 million rows like the following;

```
chr1:25851453-25869713W:6655:4522:4234:2258:2508:S      6655
chr1:25851453-25869713W:6655:4523:4234:2258:2508:A      6655
chr1:25851453-25869713W:0000:4524:4234:2258:2508:S      6655
chr1:25851453-25869713W:6655:4525:4234:2258:2508:S      6655
chr1:26235471-26237662W:6663:124:1864:311:455:S         6663
chr1:26235471-26237662W:6663:125:1864:311:455:S         6663
```

I am trying to report for each distinct element in column 2, how many times the pattern after the second ":" in column 1 matches the pattern in column 2.

So something like this for the above example;

```
6655 matches 3
6655 mismatches 1
6663 matches 2
6663 mismatches 0
```

(to be specific there are 15559 distinct values in column 2)

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you post some code you've done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[:\t]" }
prev != $NF { if (NR>1) prt(); prev = $NF }
{ cnt[$3 == $NF]++ }
END { prt() }
function prt() {
    printf "%d matches %d\n", prev, cnt[1]
    printf "%d mismatches %d\n", prev, cnt[0]
    delete cnt
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
6655 matches 3
6655 mismatches 1
6663 matches 2
6663 mismatches 0
```

Since your file is large, the above uses the fact that the key values (the last number on each line) are grouped together to allow us to just print the results when the current key value changes instead of storing the data for all key values in an array and then printing it at the end of the file.

Comment: Thank you! this worked fine and very fast after sorting the file by the second column.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `strsplit` for this:

```
lapply(setNames(unique(df[, 2]), unique(df[, 2])), function(x)
    sum(x == sapply(strsplit(as.character(df[, 1]), ":"), function(y) y[3])))
#$`6655`
#[1] 3
#
#$`6663`
#[1] 2
```

Explanation: We first determine unique entries from column 2; then for every unique entry we count the number of matches with entries after the second `":"` by splitting column 1 entries on `":"`.

This returns the number of *matches* as a `list`.

The converse case for the number of *mismatches* is straightforward and I leave that up to you.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "chr1:25851453-25869713W:6655:4522:4234:2258:2508:S 6655
chr1:25851453-25869713W:6655:4523:4234:2258:2508:A 6655
chr1:25851453-25869713W:0000:4524:4234:2258:2508:S 6655
chr1:25851453-25869713W:6655:4525:4234:2258:2508:S 6655
chr1:26235471-26237662W:6663:124:1864:311:455:S 6663
chr1:26235471-26237662W:6663:125:1864:311:455:S 6663", header = F)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer & explanation. This works fine but my problem was mostly that the file is huge and it takes around 20hrs. But apparently working good for smaller data sets.

Comment: No worries @zkaragoz; I hadn't realised that you were looking for `awk`/non-R solutions.

Answer (score 0):

One can first extract the `FirstElement` after 2nd `:` in `column1` using `gsub`. Then a solution using `dplyr` can be to group on column2 (e.g. `V2`) and then count `V2` matching and non-matching with `FirstElement` as:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
   mutate(FirstElement = gsub("^chr1:[^:]*:(\\d+):.*","\\1",V1)) %>%
  group_by(V2) %>%
  summarise(matches = sum(V2==FirstElement), mismatches = sum(V2!=FirstElement))

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#      V2 matches mismatches
#   <int>   <int>      <int>
# 1  6655       3          1
# 2  6663       2          0
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text="
chr1:25851453-25869713W:6655:4522:4234:2258:2508:S 6655
chr1:25851453-25869713W:6655:4523:4234:2258:2508:A 6655
chr1:25851453-25869713W:0000:4524:4234:2258:2508:S 6655
chr1:25851453-25869713W:6655:4525:4234:2258:2508:S 6655
chr1:26235471-26237662W:6663:124:1864:311:455:S 6663
chr1:26235471-26237662W:6663:125:1864:311:455:S 6663",
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```